# ExceptionInInitializer Error while Reading Data from teradata table using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, teradata

I am using the below code to read data from teradata but getting error

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url",s"jdbc:teradata://${TeradataDBHost}/database=${TeradataDBDatabase}")
  .option("dbtable", TeradataDBDatabase+"."+TeradataDBTable)
  .option("driver","com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver")
  .option("user", TeradataDBUsername)
  .option("password", TeradataDBPassword)
  .load()
```

Error Stack Trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.GenericTeraEncrypt.getGSSM(GenericTeraEncrypt.java:577)
            at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.GenericTeraEncrypt.<init>(GenericTeraEncrypt.java:116)
            at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.GenericTeradataConnection.<init>(GenericTeradataConnection.java:107)
            at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.<init>(TDSession.java:186)
            at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_Connection.<init>(JDK6_SQL_Connection.java:36)
            at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6ConnectionFactory.constructSQLConnection(JDK6ConnectionFactory.java:25)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.teradata.tdgss.jtdgss.TdgssConfigApi.GetMechanisms(Unknown Source)
        at com.teradata.tdgss.jtdgss.TdgssManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.teradata.tdgss.jtdgss.TdgssManager.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Teradata JDBC driver documentation](https://teradata-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_5.html#CHDIJJJH):

> If you receive one of the following exceptions:
>
> - NullPointerException at com.teradata.tdgss.jtdgss.TdgssConfigApi.GetMechanisms
> - IllegalArgumentException "InputStream cannot be null" at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse, at com.teradata.tdgss.jtdgss.TdgssParseXml.parse
>
> then the problem may be
>   due to the classpath not being set, or the classpath being set
>   incorrectly, such that tdgssconfig.jar cannot be found.

So I would guess that `tdgssconfig.jar` can't be found on the classpath.

Of course, it would be nice if the JDBC driver could have thrown a more helpful error message than an NPE.  I am somewhat concerned that this appears to be a 'known issue' with the driver: I can't imagine it would take much effort to throw a more helpful exception in this situation.  It doesn't say much for them if they have chosen to document this behaviour rather than fix it.

(Acknowledgement: found via [this Teradata Community post](http://community.teradata.com/t5/Connectivity/JDBC-driver-NullPointerException-TdgssConfigApi-GetMechanisms/td-p/72618).)