# What permission is needed for a JDBC driver connection?

Tags: java, jdbc, java-security

External code in packaged in `jar` file. It contains the following simple code

```
 Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

This jar runs from a sandbox.

**It works well when I implement `AllPermission`**

```
Permissions permissions = new Permissions(); 
permissions.add(new AllPermission));
```

**However when I impose restrictions it throws an error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.teradata.tdgss.jtdgss.TdgssConfigApi.GetMechanisms(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the list of permissions I use

```
Permissions permissions = new Permissions(); 
permissions.add(new FilePermission(filePermission, "read,write,delete")); 
permissions.add(new PropertyPermission("*", "read,write")); 
permissions.add(new SocketPermission("*", "connect,resolve")); 
permissions.add(new NetPermission("setDefaultAuthenticator,requestPasswordAuthentication")); 
permissions.add(new SerializablePermission("enableSubstitution,enableSubclassImplementation")); 
permissions.add(new ReflectPermission("suppressAccessChecks")); 
// what permission is missing for the JDBC to work?
```

What other permission is needed for a JDBC driver to work?

Comment: Turn all permissions on, then debug which permissions are checked, by enabling `access` logging: [Troubleshooting Security](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/troubleshooting-security.html)

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47233040/exceptionininitializer-error-while-reading-data-from-teradata-table-using-spark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/configuring-the-oracle-jdbc-security-policy-file) on JDBC security there are quite a few permissions to set.

The `SQLPermission` is probably missing, others need to be figured out. @Andreas provided a great article [on troubleshooting security](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/troubleshooting-security.html) to do that.

Comment: That blog is about the Oracle JDBC driver, the OP is asking about the Teradata JDBC driver. They are not the same thing.

Comment: JDBC itself has no permissions for connecting itself (although if you use a socket, you of course will need to have an appropriate permission for that socket). It only has permissions for some extra functionality in the driver (see the list of permissions in `SQLPermission`). The problem here seems to do with the authentication using a GSS api.

Comment: Thank you. SQLPermission doesn't help. I thought allowing Socket is enought, but there seems to be something i'm missing. I know it's one of the permissions, because when I use `AllPermission` it works

Comment: @John What do you mean 'seems'? The stack trace tells what permission was missing, and so does the tracing mentioned by Andreas. There is no need to guess about this.

Comment: You are right. it looks like sql permission is not needed. the issue because it has extracted jars