# Cannot connect to Teradata database through JDBC (Connection broken)

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, teradata, aster

I'm trying to connect to a teradata database, i've followed the [documentation example](https://docs.teradata.com/r/fxS6ycE43kzSZmrTW2mrhQ/h8n9e9UlHvzWmusgk2vJ4Q), and other examples on the web, but i cannot connect

```
    String host= "X"; 
    int port=XXXX;
    String database="X";
    String username = "X";
    String password = "X";
    String url = "jdbc:ncluster://"+host+":"+port+"/"+database;
    
    Properties localProperties = new Properties();
    localProperties.put("user", username);
    localProperties.put("password", password);

    Class.forName("com.asterdata.ncluster.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, localProperties);
```

However with this code i get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [AsterData][ASTERJDBCDSII](34) : Database connection broken ()
at com.asterdata.ncluster.jdbc.core.NClusterConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.simba.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at com.simba.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
at poc.TeradataConnection.main(TeradataConnection.java:31)
Caused by: com.asterdata.ncluster.jdbc.core.MuleException: [AsterData][ASTERJDBCDSII](34) : Database connection broken ()
... 6 more
```

When i try to use another driver class, like said in their [official documentation](https://teradata-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#URL_LOGDATA)

```
String url_teradata = "jdbc:teradata://"+host+"/database="+database
Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url_teradata,username,password);
```

I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.GenericTeraEncrypt.getGSSM(GenericTeraEncrypt.java:577)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.GenericTeraEncrypt.<init>(GenericTeraEncrypt.java:116)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.GenericTeradataConnection.<init>(GenericTeradataConnection.java:108)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.<init>(TDSession.java:187)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_Connection.<init>(JDK6_SQL_Connection.java:36)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6ConnectionFactory.constructSQLConnection(JDK6ConnectionFactory.java:25)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:181)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:171)
at com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver.doConnect(TeraDriver.java:236)
at com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver.connect(TeraDriver.java:162)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at poc.TeradataConnection.main(TeradataConnection.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.teradata.tdgss.jtdgss.TdgssConfigApi.GetMechanisms(Unknown Source)
at com.teradata.tdgss.jtdgss.TdgssManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.teradata.tdgss.jtdgss.TdgssManager.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
... 13 more
```

I've seen that this issue could be related to the [tdgssconfig.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47238436/6324980)

But teradata integrated this jar into the terajdbc4.jar, so i'm lost.

The versions of the terajdbc4 and the noarch-aster-jdbc-driver are the following

```
        <dependency>
         <groupId>com.teradata.jdbc</groupId>
         <artifactId>terajdbc4</artifactId>
         <version>16.20.00.10</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency> 
         <groupId>com.teradata.jdbc</groupId>
         <artifactId>aster-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
         <version>6.10.00.02</version>
       </dependency>
```

When using the Teradata SQL Assistant utility, i am able to connect to the database with the same info i put in my code

Comment: As that documentation indicates, up through JDBC driver version 16.20.00.10 you need both terajdbc4.jar and tdgssconfig.jar in your CLASSPATH. Starting from 16.20.00.11 you need only terajdbc4.jar. (Also the Aster / ncluster driver is something completely different for a different product, not Teradata database aka SQL Engine.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Fred mentioned in his commment, i was missing a version, even if there was the tgssconfig libraries in the teradjdbc4 jar, it wasn't enough, i upgraded the terajdbc to 17.00.00.03 and it worked.